# Looking to add a calculator to calculate today's calories for a food application

Tags: java, android, android-studio, calculator

Looking to add a calorie counter, for all food added to a running total.

I currently have 2 spinners, 1 food type (breakfast etc), the other is the food itself dependent on the food type selected (breakfast = cereal etc).

I've added a weight input so the user can select their food and food weight. I want to take these inputed values to allow the calculation of Today's calories. I just don't know how to do that. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create an [Enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) that represents Food, declare a constant for each food such as calories per 100 grams.
2. Get a food string from your spinner, find the constant mentioned above and store it into a variable.
3. Get the weight from your spinner/edittext, store it to a variable and convert it to double/integer/float for further calculations.
4. Do the math (kCal = foodKcalPer100 * weight) or something similiar.
5. Show the result or store it.